# The type initializer for 'PayPal.Manager.ConfigManager' threw an exception -->Paypal SetExpressCheckout

Tags: c#, paypal, express-checkout

I'm having some trouble using PayPal's API. When I try to make a call to the SetExpressCheckout method, (and I believe I've added the same items/classes as in the example), I get the following error:

```
The type initializer for 'PayPal.Manager.ConfigManager' threw an exception.
```

The inner exception given was:

```
{"Cannot read config file"}
```

This lead me to a thought: My PayPal API-calling methods are in one assembly, and I have a web service that calls the methods in this assembly to use the PayPal APIs. Quite simply, it works like this:

```
Web Service ---calls---> Assembly ---calls---> PayPal API
```

Does anybody know why this occurs? It really baffles me, how it can work within the example project, but not work within my own.

Comment: Consider looking at the "Inner Exception" to get the exact type of the exception.

Comment: The inner exception shows: {"Cannot read config file"}

Have you guys got any experience with the PayPal SDKs? Do you know what might be causing this?

Comment: One thought, that I forgot to mention in my post (I'll change that now) is I have the PayPal API-calling code in one assembly, and I am calling that assembly's methods from a web service in an ASP.NET project.

Answer (score 3):

Since it doesn't appear any answers to this yet and I ran into the same error implementing the PayPal API in a MVC3 .Net application, the following worked for me.  It is taken straight from the PayPal API Sample .Net Project Web.Config:

In your Web.Config file, at the top (as the first child element) add a reference as follows:

```
<configSections>
  <section name="paypal" type="PayPal.Manager.SDKConfigHandler, PayPal_Merchant_SDK" />
</configSections>
```

Then add the PayPal SDK Config

```
<paypal>
  <settings>
    <!-- The URL that the user must be redirected to in order to login and approve some payment actions-->
    <add name="paypalUrl" value="https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/webscr?cmd="/>
    <!-- The API endpoint -->
    <add name="endpoint" value="https://api-3t.sandbox.paypal.com/2.0"/>
    <!-- Connection timeout in milliseconds -->
    <add name="connectionTimeout" value="360000"/>
    <!-- The number of times a request must be retried if the API endpoint is   unresponsive -->
    <add name="requestRetries" value="3"/>
    <add name="binding" value="SOAP"/>
    <add name="IPAddress" value="127.0.0.1"/>
    <!-- 
      API version number. You will not normally have to change this unless you
      have a specific need to work with an older version of the API
     -->
    <add name="APIVersion" value="84.0"/>
  </settings>

  <accounts>
    <!--
      Add API credentials - 3 token or client certificate.
      You can add multiple account credentials here. The SDK will pick the first   account
      unless you specifically request an account in the service wrapper mehod.
    -->
    <account apiUsername="sdk-three_api1.sdk.com" apiPassword="QFZCWN5HZM8VBG7Q"
        apiSignature="A-IzJhZZjhg29XQ2qnhapuwxIDzyAZQ92FRP5dqBzVesOkzbdUONzmOU"   applicationId="APP-80W284485P519543T"/>
    <!--
    <account apiUsername="enduser_biz_api1.gmail.com" apiPassword="SACH3VA3C29DXGUG"
      apiCertificate="<Absolute path to paypal_cert.p12>" 
             privateKeyPassword="password" applicationId="APP-80W284485P519543T"/>
     -->           
  </accounts>
</paypal>
```

Comment: I installed the PayPalMerchantSDK nuget package instead of the PayPal_Merchant_SDK package.  I am not sure what the difference is, but I had to change one line (besides the credential-specific stuff): `<section name="paypal" type="PayPal.Manager.SDKConfigHandler, PayPalCoreSDK" />`.  Other than that, it worked like a charm.  Thanks for setting me on the right track.  I wish I could approve this answer.